# No Deactive script in Python venv

Tags: python, virtual-environment

I have created virtual environment, activated to work. I found that there is no Deactivate to exit venv. i'm using Ubuntu LTS 20.x on wsl(Windows Subsystem for Linux)

```
(venv) airflow@xxxxxxx:~/Dataengineer/venv/bin$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 1 airflow airflow 4096 Oct  8 14:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 airflow airflow 4096 Oct  8 14:09 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 airflow airflow 8834 Oct  8 14:09 Activate.ps1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 airflow airflow 2190 Oct  8 14:09 activate
-rw-r--r-- 1 airflow airflow 1242 Oct  8 14:09 activate.csh
-rw-r--r-- 1 airflow airflow 2394 Oct  8 14:09 activate.fish
-rwxr-xr-x 1 airflow airflow  257 Oct  8 14:09 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x 1 airflow airflow  257 Oct  8 14:09 easy_install-3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 airflow airflow  248 Oct  8 14:09 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 airflow airflow  248 Oct  8 14:09 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 airflow airflow  248 Oct  8 14:09 pip3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 airflow airflow    7 Oct  8 14:09 python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 airflow airflow   16 Oct  8 14:09 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
(venv) airflow@AIINDIA-BKOYYALAMUDI:~/Dataengineer/venv/bin$
```

Pls advise.

Comment: Just enter the command `deactivate`.

Comment: You don't need one. Just exit the shell and you are good.